# c++ Closing cout properly

Tags: c++, daemon, cout

I wanted to write a daemon which acts as a remote shell. As such I have to close stdin, stdout and stderr.

Now I would like to know how this is properly done.

```
std::streambuf * old = std::cout.rdbuf(mStdOut.rdbuf());
std::cout << "Bla" << std::endl;
std::string text = mStdOut.str();
```

This works and the stream is now redirected. But what is the meaning of 'old'? Isn't this the old buffer and should be deleted? When I try to delete it I get a null pointer exception, even though the pointer itself is not NULL. So how can iget rid of it, or can I simply ignore it? if to ignore it, is the daemon disassociated from the terminal properly?

The same goes for stderr and stdin, but I assume the treatement would be the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is close the actual file descriptors. This is of course platform-specific, but so are deamons. So for POSIX platforms you use the POSIX API for this. After you redirect `cout`, you do:

```
close(STDIN_FILENO);
close(STDOUT_FILENO);
close(STDERR_FILENO);
```

You might also want to read:

http://www.netzmafia.de/skripten/unix/linux-daemon-howto.html

Answer (score 3):

You should restore the original buffer to `cout` before terminating the program.

You cannot delete it because you don't know if it is dynamically allocated (or if some other code will call delete, if it is).

Comment: While true, this does nothing to answer the question. The answer is that it can't be done via `cin`/`cout`/`cerr`, but must be done to the underlying POSIX file handles.

Comment: Ok, so there are two parts in the question. I answered the C++ and `cout` part - don't delete the streambuffer.